# Angular.js - $scope not being interpolated

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an Angular.js app and for some reason I cannot interpolate out anything on the `$scope` object into the HTML.  My `MainCtrl` controller and `MainFactory` work fine together and I can append a graph to the html properly, just interpolating the `$scope` is not working.  Here is the code that I currently have:

**EDIT:** I am using this with the view rendering engine Swig

```
var app = angular.module("myapp", []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, MainFactory) {
    $scope.firstName = 'George';

    console.log('scope :', $scope);  // logs the $scope obj correctly but doesn't have my firstName property on it

    MainFactory.fetchBacktestedDataByAllocationId()
    .then(data => {
        // draw and append chart - works fine
    });
});


app.factory('MainFactory', function($http) {
    var MainFactory = {};

    MainFactory.fetchBacktestedDataByAllocationId = function() {
        return $http.get('/path/to/api')
        .then(response => {
            return response.data;
        })
    };

    return MainFactory;
});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
                integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
                crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="/widget/assets/d3.version3.js"></script>
        <script src="/widget/assets/backtested-growth/backtested-data-chart.js"></script>
        <script src="/widget/assets/backtested-growth/backtested-growth.script.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-app="myapp">
        <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">

            <div style="width: 100%;">
                <div id="graph-div"></div>
                <br>
                <p>First Name: {{ firstName }}</p>
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that any other script or view-engine (if you are using it with some server rendering engine like handlebar, ejs) may also be using symbols `{{`.

Try changing angular interpolation symbol with this,

```
app.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
  });
```

and see if that works.

Comment: @georgej Once it also bothered me for a long time :)